# Follow-up mail after initial interview for a postdoc position

Tags: postdocs, job, interview

I had a zoom meeting with my possible future boss about a postdoc position, and I thought it was quit good. After the meeting, we exchanged a few mails, but after that, the responses halted.
A week ago, I sent another email and did not receive a response yet.

I thought about sending a follow-up email to the possible future boss with CCing a member of the lab, to ensure the mail would be read. Will this be a bad choice?